# Javascript Gradient Background Form to Table

Tags: javascript, forms, linear-gradients

I am kind of new at this and don't really know where to start. What I am wanting to do is create a webpage where you can use a form to submit two colors. Then I want a table that when you hit a button the background color of the cell will become a gradient of the two colors that were selected. Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script>
function updateColor(){
    var col1 = document.getElementById('color1').value;
    var col2 = document.getElementById('color2').value;
    var myCell = document.getElementById('mycell');     
        myCell.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right," + col1 + "," col2 + ");";            
}
</script>

<select id="color1">
<option value="0">set background color    
<option value="red">red
<option value="yellow">yellow
<option value="blue">blue
<option value="green">green
<option value="black">black
</select><br />

<select id="color2">
<option value="0">set background color    
<option value="red">red
<option value="yellow">yellow
<option value="blue">blue
<option value="green">green
<option value="black">black
</select>

<button onclick="updatecolor();">Gradient</button>

<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>One
    </td>
    <td>Two
    </td>
    <td id="mycell">Three
    </td>
    <td>Four
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am not great at this, I know it can be done with one color as the background but I was wanting a duel color gradient.

Comment: Please provide what you tried and the picture you are going to build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just had some small typos in there, this should fix it:

```js
function updateColor(){
    var col1 = document.getElementById('color1').value;
    var col2 = document.getElementById('color2').value;
    var myCell = document.getElementById('mycell');
    mycell.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right, " + col1 + ", " + col2 + ")";
}
```

```html
<select id="color1">
<option value="0">set background color
<option value="red">red
<option value="yellow">yellow
<option value="blue">blue
<option value="green">green
<option value="black">black
</select><br />

<select id="color2">
<option value="0">set background color
<option value="red">red
<option value="yellow">yellow
<option value="blue">blue
<option value="green">green
<option value="black">black
</select>

<button onclick="updateColor();">Gradient</button>

<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>One
    </td>
    <td>Two
    </td>
    <td id="mycell">Three
    </td>
    <td>Four
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly. I never would have figured it out without your help.